# Re-reflow of older car radio's PCB

Tags: radio, reflow, pcb-double-sided

I have a 2006 Jeep WK/H REC/REJ, depending on region, the screen of which has ceased to function.

It has been suggested to me that reflowing the Nav board (only accessible PCB in the unit) may - at least temporarily - rectify the problem. The idea is that over the last 16 years, some whiskering has occurred and the contacts reduced.

This isn't a skill I've picked up yet, so I have a few questions. Unfortunately, a straight replacement is not an option - where I live, unguaranteed refurbished units go north of €600.

First: is this even realistic? Some forum guys have seen temporary success. And it's not like I can break the unit more at this point.

Second: what do I even need to do to a re-reflow of a double sided board? I've found plenty of info on how to do the initial double-sided flow, but not so much for a re-reflow.

I've heard of just throwing it into a toaster oven once, I've heard of turning it over and putting it back in, heat guns, hair dryers, electric frying pans(?), some people talk about flux, some say no-flux-necessary. What is the right or fairly reliable DIY method?

I'm fairly comfortable at this point that parts aren't just going to fall off, as that tends to be something most people agree on.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the board top and bottom? I've had reflowing work when BGAs failed due to thermal cycling (two expensive CAD monitors- one was replaced under warranty and then it and its sister both failed). I reflowed the boards and retrofitted small fans. So far so good.

Comment: Hmm it looks like I don't have one right now. I'll have to get one later. I do have the board part number though BZCY603A  PANEL. NAVI 84-04041Z01-A

Comment: Depends on how complex the board is. If there's BGA or QFN etc then an oven is the only way. If not, then you can probably just tidy it up with a soldering iron.

Comment: Definitely forget about toasters, heat guns, hair dryers and frying pans however. There's no way you can control the temperature on those. Regarding flux, it can never cause harm (unless it's perhaps some delicate RF design) - applying it extensively is always a good thing.

Comment: "refurbished units go north of €600" And yeah well... what do you think a reflow oven will cost?